# Javascript regex throwing syntax error in edge

Tags: javascript, regex, microsoft-edge

I have a simple regex I'm using and that works perfectly in chrome but edge throws a syntax error, ths is the line :

```
var html=text.match(/^<div.+\/div>$/ims);
```

I don't see the problem.

Comment: `s flag` is not supported in `IE`, [`DotAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/dotAll)

Comment: In JS, use `[^]` instead of `.` to match ny char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `/s` flag is not supported, use:

```
var html=text.match(/^<div[\s\S]+\/div>$/im);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to match all characters with a new line character 
You can this regex please:-

```
text.match(/^<div>.+\n*.*<\/div>/)
```

Comment: This will match only one linefeed and will not match div with attributes.